# Redshift : Syntax Check Utilities

Tags: amazon-redshift

If you know any good sql syntax check tool for Redshift, could you kindly advise me?

So far, I use SQLWorkbenchJ and AginityRedshiftWorkbench as connection tool, and SCT as migration tool. They actually help me a lot though, just I'm wondering if there are any other good utilities for syntax or intelligence check purpose.

Other useful conection tool would be also appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Jetbrains DataGrip is very good - I would not be without it,

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt advice, @JonScott :)’ I’m sure to try it !!

Comment: Dbeaver... try it

Comment: Dear @Gagan Thank you so much for your useful advice!! (sorry for my late reply. I notice it now)  Also I'll try Dbeaver soon, I really love his cute icon  :)